# Using Processing with Eclipse: close sketch without closing the rest of the windows?

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I'm working on a Java project in Eclipse that has a class extending PApplet to run a Processing sketch.

First I have a JFrame login screen, and after the user logs in there, I call

```
PApplet.main("Game"); //"Game" is the class that extends PApplet
```

to start the sketch.

Now when the game ends I want to close the sketch window, but not the original JFrame window.

Normally I would call

```
exit();
```

in Processing but this closes the entire application (ie all windows).

I have also tried

```
dispose();
```

but this does nothing.

I guess I'm looking for something like

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

but for PApplet.

Comment: What version of Processing are you using?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to get the instance holding your sketch. That means using the `runSketch()` function instead of calling `main()` directly:

```
Game game = new Game();
String[] args = {};
PApplet.runSketch(args, game);
```

Now that you have a reference to your sketch instance, you can use it to get to the internal window. How you do this depends on which renderer you're using, but you can figure it out using a mix of [the Processing JavaDoc](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/) and [the Processing source code](https://github.com/processing/processing/tree/master/core/src/processing).

Here's an **untested** example using the default renderer:

```
PSurface surface = game.getSurface();
SmoothCanvas smoothCanvas = (SmoothCanvas)surface.getNative();
JFrame frame = (JFrame) smoothCanvas.getFrame();
```

Now that you have the parent window, you can do whatever you want with it, including:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(false);
```

Like I said I haven't tested this code, and this is going to depend on exactly which renderer you're using, but this process of using the source code and JavaDoc to figure out what's going on under the hood to get to the underlying window is what you have to do.

Comment: PApplet.runSketch(args,game); yields "Usage: PApplet [options] <class name> [sketch args]
See the Javadoc for PApplet for an explanation."

Comment: @EricNewsom What version of Processing are you using? [Here](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#runSketch-java.lang.String:A-processing.core.PApplet-) is a link to the JavaDoc for the function you need to call.